# Remove label from chart when exporting

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export

My chart contains a custom label which I have put in the lower left as follows:

```
events: {
    load: function () {
        var label = this.renderer.label('Custom label goes here')
            .css({
                width: '450px',
                color: '#E4E6E5',
                fontSize: '12px'
            }).add();
        label.align(Highcharts.extend(label.getBBox(), {
            align: 'left',
            x: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            y: 15
        }), null, 'spacingBox');
    }
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that this label is not included when exporting the chart? If there isn't a way to remove it, maybe there is a way to change the font color of the label when exporting so that you can't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set additional options for the exported chart using [exporting.chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions).

In your case, you can 'reset' the callback on load, it will cause that the custom label will not be rendered for the exported chart.

```
exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function () {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/17Ltco4k/